# ~2,000,000 seek errors on SpinRite?

Tags: hard-drive, spinrite

I ran a level 4 maintenance level on my hard drive with [SpinRite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpinRite). Everything was clean, but I checked the log and it said that it found ~2,000,000 seek errors. That's the only thing that SpinRite found. Is that something to worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it might be a S.M.A.R.T. value, if so, then this is not an actual decimal number, it is a raw value and its actual value is dependent on the drive manufacturer.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes) for more info.

Run a S.M.A.R.T. monitoring tool from inside an OS and see what that says.

Comment: I ran HD Sentinel and it reported my hard drive as 100% health, so I think its fine. Thx.